# Mysql client hangs when returning large result sets

Tags: mysql, mac

I have a strange problem on one Mac: when doing selects that return large result sets (> 10.000 rows), the sql client on that machine hangs. It does not return anything and just waits. All other machines can run the query without any problem. Even more strange: that Mac can do that query on the staging mysql without any problems. It only has problems with the live mysql server instance.

Is there any advice what I should check? The my.cnf is the same as the config on the other macs.

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using on MAC?

Comment: I tried a few versions. The current installed is "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.20, for osx10.7 (i386) using readline 5.1", installed with homebrew.

Comment: Any my.cnf differences between staging and live MySQL environments?

Comment: none that i can see. the my.cnf is the same.